# AttributeError "int" Object Has No Attribute 'txinc'

Tags: object, attributes, integer, int, range

I keep receiving the error that "int" object has no attribute "txinc." I'm not sure how to fix this. My final output should be total tax. The error is occurring in the tax calculators, specifically with the range function. It should be an integer.

```
import sys
class TaxComp:
   def __init__(self, total_deductions= None, real_estate_deduc= None, exemption_amount= None, taxable_income= None, tax_taxable_income= None, 
             computed_regular_tax= None, inc_tax_before_credits= None, inc_subject_to_tax= None, marginal_tax_base= None, tax_generated= None, AMT= None):

                 self.total_deductions = total_deductions or 'total_deductions'
                 self.real_estate_deduc = real_estate_deduc or 'real_estate_deduc'
                 self.exemption_amount = exemption_amount or 'exemption_amount'
                 self.taxable_income = taxable_income or 'taxable_income'
                 self.tax_taxable_income = tax_taxable_income or 'tax_taxable_income' 
                 self.computed_regular_tax = computed_regular_tax or 'computed_regular_tax'
                 self.inc_tax_before_credits = inc_tax_before_credits or 'inc_tax_before_credits'
                 self.inc_subject_to_tax = inc_subject_to_tax or 'inc_subject_to_tax'
                 self.marginal_tax_base = marginal_tax_base or 'marginal_tax_base'
                 self.tax_generated = tax_generated or 'tax_generated'
                 self.AMT = AMT or 'AMT'

class TaxableIncome:
  def taxable_Income(self, AGI):

      taxable_inc = AGI - 6300
      taxable_inc -= 4000

class Totals:

  txcomp = TaxComp()
  def __init__(self, taxable_income = txcomp.taxable_income): 
    txinc = TaxableIncome()
    self.taxable_income = taxable_income or txinc.taxable_Income.taxable_inc

class TaxCal:

  def __init__(self):
    self.brackets = {(0,8025):0.10, (8025,32550):.15, (32550,78850):.25, (78850, 164550):.28, (164550,357700):.33, (357700,371815):.35, (371815, sys.maxsize):.396}     

  def taxcal (self, tot):
    tax = 0       
    for bracket in self.brackets:
      if tot.txinc.taxable_Income.taxable_inc > bracket[0]:
          for _ in range(bracket[0], min(int(tot.txinc.taxable_Income.taxable_inc), bracket[1])):
              tax += self.brackets[bracket]
  return tax

AGI = 100000
txcal = TaxCal()
tot = Totals()
print(txcal.taxcal(AGI)), format(round(txcal.taxcal(AGI),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want "txinc = TaxableIncome()" to be "self.txinc = TaxableIncome()" and thereby also the following: "self.txinc.taxable_Income.taxable_inc"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are passing AGI to taxal which takes tot as class Totals.
Maybe you want "if tot.txinc.taxable_Income.taxable_inc > bracket[0]:" to be just "if tot > bracket[0]:"

Comment: No luck there either. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: The following line "min(int(tot.txinc.taxable_Income.taxable_inc)" would probably also return the same error "min(int(tot))" would work, but not really make sense from just "tot" maybe you meant something like int(floor(tot))?